# should have instead of could have

Tags: grammar, expressions, speech

I've heard this on a crime documentary. Two intruders break into a house, a confrontation ensues with the residents (wife and husband). The couple manages to disarm one man and fight off the other. But they had to shoot one of them. Whatever. At the end the husband goes like this:

> "And what should've happened to my wife is my wife should've been
>   dead. My kids could've been dead. What happened to them is what
>   should've happened to us."

I think he uses could've instead of should've here because it doesn't make any sense otherwise. Is this usage common? I've never heard it before.

The documentary is: Over My Dead Body (Go to the safe place)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My wife should've been dead - This means that she was in extreme danger and she was very lucky to escape death.

My kids could've been dead - this means that the children were not in immediate danger (maybe they were in a different room) but the possibility was there - especially if the parents hadn't survived.

**Edited in response to comment**

Here is a formal example. It also exposes more of the implied structure of your original sentences.

> *Before long he had shot down more of the big bombers ... than anyone else and by any normal standards **he should have been decorated** for it.*
>
> The Final Hours: The Luftwaffe Plot Against Goring By Johannes Steinhoff

Comment: So this is not colloquial? I thought it was not grammatical.

Comment: @aytug2001 - It is grammatical and can be formal. See my new example.